# How to get the edited image from UIImagePickerController in Swift?

Tags: swift, ios8, uiimagepickercontroller

I have seen and read the [documents of Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate/imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:) where they have clearly mentioned about the key [UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Editing_Information_Keys).  But when I am running my following code, I am not getting that key in the Dictionary. What is the reason behind this?

My Code:

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController!, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info:NSDictionary!)
    {
        println(info)

        //var tempImage:UIImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as UIImage
        var tempImage:UIImage? = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage] as? UIImage

        profileButton.setImage(tempImage, forState: UIControlState(0))

        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion:nil)

    }
```

println(info) prints:

```
{
    UIImagePickerControllerMediaType = "public.image";
    UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage = "<UIImage: 0x178295d60> size {960, 960} orientation 0 scale 1.000000";
    UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL = "assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=2DDCE06B-6082-4167-A631-B3DF627055DF&ext=JPG";
}
```

FYI, I am picking image from Library and I tried from Camera also, but this key is still not coming but the other data about image is coming. And I am using iOS8.0 build SDK.

**So how can I use `UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage`if there is no such key coming in the dictionary.**

Comment: Its seems like that you haven't enabled `allowEditing` property of image picker, you need to set `<pickerInstanceName>.allowEditing = true` before presenting the `UIImagePickerController` to the window

Answer (score 10):

**SWIFT 3.0**:

Add `UINavigationControllerDelegate` and `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate`

```
var imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()

@IBAction func btnSelectPhotoOnClick(_ sender: UIButton)
{
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Choose Image", message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Camera", style: .default, handler: { _ in
        self.openCamera()
    }))

    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Gallery", style: .default, handler: { _ in
        self.openGallary()
    }))

    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction.init(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil))

    imagePicker.delegate = self
    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
func openCamera()
{
    if(UIImagePickerController .isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera))
    {
        imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = true
        self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    else
    {
        let alert  = UIAlertController(title: "Warning", message: "You don't have camera", preferredStyle: .alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil))
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
func openGallary()
{
    imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.photoLibrary
    imagePicker.allowsEditing = true
    self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}


func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
//You will get cropped image here..
    if let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage] as? UIImage
    {
        self.imageView.image = image
    }   
}
```

Comment: Hi @Anas could you please tell how to pick edited video using swift. I am able to use normal video but not able to get edited one.

Answer (score 9):

You can do it like this.

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {

    let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage] as UIImage
}
```

Comment: You are fetching value for key  "UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage" but its not present in the dictionary "info". This is the problem I am facing!

Comment: I have tested this on an iPad with iOS 7 and simulator with iOS 8 and it works as well as shows the `UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage` when you `println("\(info)")` I did notice a difference in the way things are printed when changing `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [NSObject : AnyObject]` to `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info:NSDictionary!` do you get some kind of error if you use the above code? What version of Xcode are you using?

Comment: Dude! I have mentioned the response also in my question and I also mentioned that base SDK is 8.0 so obviously I am using xcode 6X.
BTW I am using XCode 6.1 (not Beta)

Comment: hi @Developer - you really need to TICK this answer.

Answer (score 4):

I found the cause of the issue! Its because of the property "allowsEditing" which was set to **false**! I have changed that to **true** and now it is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 4.2**

```
if let editedImage = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.editedImage] as? UIImage {
        // Use editedImage Here
    }
```

Comment: I got this error

Cannot subscript a value of type '[String : AnyObject]' with an index of type 'UIImagePickerController.InfoKey'

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you allowed to editing image in `UIImagePickerController`.

You can allow `UIImagePickerController` to edit the `UIImage` by making this

`picker.allowsEditing = true`