# Editing existing image with UIImagePickerController

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller, edit, photo

Is it possible to use the `UIImagePickerController` to edit an image in an `UIImageView`? I am able to take and pick a picture but I want to use the imagepicker's edit mode to edit an image I have already picked and show on a view.

```
imagePicker = nil
        imagePicker =  UIImagePickerController()
        imagePicker.delegate = self
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = true
        imagePicker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
        present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Try this link, hope this will help! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26502931/how-to-get-the-edited-image-from-uiimagepickercontroller-in-swift

Comment: I want to use the UIImagePickerController to edit an image I already have in an UIImageView. I don't want to make the user take or pick an image, just use the edit functionality for an image I send.

Comment: I don't think this is even possible. I did some research for your requirements as well and read about "UIImagePickerController" on Apple Developers Forum. But didn't find anything that you require. I'll suggest you to use some photo editing libraries to get this done.